# c# call windows service from web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

I have created windows service to export the files to the ftp.

The windows service will run in 30 seconds interval using the timer.

For ftp configuration details like username and password, we can configure through web application. The necessary username and password for ftp configuration will be saved through web application.

For this, I will store the username and password for the ftp configuration details in Database which is common for the both.

Here I want to change this timer interval through the web application.

**How to change windows service timer through web api?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the Username, Password and Time interval related details in some configurable place.
For example,
Local Database, Xml file, Encrypted file(key shared between Web & Windows application.

You can update them from your locally hosted Web Application(If you are planning to use File System as configurable place)
Or Remotely hosted Web Application in case of Database approach.

And Before each windows service interval you can read these details from above source and refresh your Configuration object.

Comment: Thanks anish.. Can't we add the reference/assembly to web api and call the windows service?

Comment: If windows service is run once in a week. Say example on Sunday. I want to change windows service to run daily on Monday. This time, the windows service time interval will change only on the next Sunday. The service need to wait till Sunday to change the timer interval . Will this correct?

Comment: If you can use File System, Like (Xml file approach) then you can implement File Watcher in your Windows Service. 
And after any changes in File details you can get event in your service and after that you can update your Service configuration details.